# RealmResults not calls RealmChangeListener.onChange()

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to listen data changes in RealmResults, adding listener

```
private RealmResults<Cargo> dataResults;
...
dataResults.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
```

but listener's method onChange() not calls when data had been changed. Listener works only when added to realm.

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'change'?

Comment: @ozgur-gul For example when item that matches RealmResult was added or removed from realm. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is currently not working as expected. Sorry about that. We are tracking it here, and are working on a fix: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1676